# Newbie - Rails View within View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, view, controller

I'm attempting to make a two column layout. The column on the left is navigation, and the column on the right is content.

Is there a way to display `show.html.erb`, `edit.html.erb`, and `new.html.erb` at different times in the right div, when the corresponding navigation is selected, without re-loading the whole page?

I know I can use a partial for the left div, and render new pages, but I want to avoid having a separate page load for each view.

Item Controller:

```
def index
    @item = item.find(:all, :order => "id DESC")
end

def new
    @item = item.new
end

def create
    @item = item.new(params[:item])

    if @item.save
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        render "new"
    end
end

def edit
    @item = item.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @item = item.find(params[:id])

    if @item.update_attributes(params[:item])
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        render "index"
    end
end
```

HTML:

```
<div id="left" ">
    <p id=link_to "Current_Item", item_path %></p>
    <p id=Link_to "Add_Item", new_item_path %></p>
    <p id=Link_to "Edit_Item", edit_item_path %></p>
</div>

<div id="right">

</div>
```

Routes File:

```
resources :items
```

Answer (score 1):

Is **"but I'm trying to avoid having a separate page load"** means that you want to load your views by ajax instead of a complete new page? If so then your links should be a `remote_link` and your views should update the `div id='right'` with the content of corresponding view.

Your links should use `:remote=>true` option. [See the details](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to).

And your view should response to update the content within the `<div id="right">`.

[Another link here](http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-3-remote-links-and-forms/) with some more insights.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend modifying `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` then put

```
<div id="left">
    <p><%= link_to "Current_Item", item_path %></p>
    <p><%= Link_to "Add_Item", new_item_path %></p>
    <p><%= Link_to "Edit_Item", edit_item_path %></p>
</div>


<div id="right">
    <%= yield %>
</div>
```

into it. Then the `show.html.erb, edit.html.erb, and new.html.erb` views should be automatically rendered for each appropriate action that gets called into the right section of your page.

Also I recommend [Rails tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book) which is a great tutorial on rails. Then go to [Codeschool](http://codeschool.com) to learn even more.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll look at the additional resources you've provided as well.